# Are there signs that shouldn't be used as command line arguments?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

The program should get input from the command line as in command line arguments type. Where after -s should be printed strings that will be connected and after -b numbers that will add up into a sum.

Normal arguments input: -s ab cd ef -b 1 2 3 it should give me string: abcdef sum: 6

Now the problem lies when i input in the string section something like: -s ab $d ef -b 1 2 3. That sign will ignore the string, also signs like: ", #, & ...

Which leads me to the question are there signs that shouldn't be used as command line arguments ?

The function prototype is:

```
void merge_add(int argc, char **argv, char* (*merge)(char *, char *), int (*add)(int, int)
```

This is the function code:

```
char *str = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
int sum = 0;
int j;

for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < argc && strcmp(argv[j], "-b"))
        {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(str) + sizeof(*argv[j]) + 1);
            strcpy(str, merge(str, argv[j]));
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-b") == 0)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < argc && strcmp(argv[j], "-s"))
        {
            sum = (*add)(sum, atoi(argv[j]));
            j++;
        }
    }
}

printf("sum:%d\n", sum);
printf("string:%s\n", str);
free(str);
```

Comment: That depends on the shell you use. In general the shell should have a way to *escape* all of those symbols, you can pretty much use any symbols you want.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I compiled it under the GNU/Linux terminal, thought the same thing then tried on CodeBlocks and some online compilers.

Comment: try `./a.out -s ab "$d" "*" "#foo" ef -b 1 2 3`

Comment: @pmg It printed everything besides $d, here is the code if you want it I'm still new and don't know how to edit the code https://pastebin.com/CKeEBmQs

Comment: [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) is related and relevant to your question.

Comment: hmmm ... I guess `"$d"` gets expanded (to nothing)... you may want to try `'$d'` (or `\$d`) instead. Your program is not responsible for changes to command-line arguments: they happen before it gets called.

Comment: In principle you can use any character but `'\0'` because your program cannot distinguish that from a normally limited string, and I'm sure the shell can't either. It all depends on the shell you use. Even good ole' `cmd` on Windows has limited capabilities to escape its special characters.